# add data on pie chart with JSON(Retrofit)

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, pie-chart

any one please help me,

how to set data on pie chart with json(retrofit)

here is my json data:

```
  {
"response": [
{
  "party_name": "Android",
  "num_rows": "4"
},
{
  "party_name": "php",
  "num_rows": "2"
},
{
  "party_name": "dotnet",
  "num_rows": "1"
},
{
  "party_name": "Other",
  "num_rows": "1"
}
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please read the  https://stackoverflow.com/help before posting questions/problems. Here developers solve or help in what you are facing problem, they are not supposed to write code. Here you did not put your efforts to solve you problem.Research on internet you can get lots of tutorials for creating pie charts, implement them.

Comment: i am already done all code but my pie chart are not shown

Comment: Post your code where you written the pie chard code and any error you are getting, Check logcat.